# Selecting latest record by date

Tags: qgis, expression, select-by-attribute, datetime

At 3.22.1 I have a GeoPackage attribute table containing the string field: `box_id` and the date field: `inspection_date`.  The table rows look like:

*box_id*         *inspection_date*
NE_01_01    2021-05-01
NE_01_01    2021-05-02
NE_01_01    2021-05-04
SE_03_02     2021-06-09
SW_01_04    2021-06-05
SW_01_04    2021-06-07
...

I need to select those records with the latest `inspection_date` for each `box_id`.  Using my example data, the resulting selection would look like:

*box_id*         *inspection_date*
NE_01_01    2021-05-04
SE_03_02     2021-06-09
SW_01_04    2021-06-07
...

I have tried this selection expression:

"inspection_date" = maximum("inspection_date", group_by:="box_id")

but it returns zero records.

What am I doing wrong?

**NOTE:**

Following the answer by Kadir Sahbaz, I did some experimentation and found that converting *inspection_date* from a date type to a string type also worked:

"inspection_date" = maximum(format_date("inspection_date", 'yyyy-MM-dd'), group_by:="box_id")

Apparently maximum() requires a string type, not a date type.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`QDateTime`object is returned from `maximum`, but `inspection_date` is probably `QDate`. And `to_date` converts the result to `QDate` object.

```
"inspection_date" = to_date(maximum("inspection_date", group_by:="box_id"))
```

Answer (score 7):

Using arrays seems to work without further modification (>= QGIS 3.18)

```
"inspection_date" =
       array_max(array_agg("inspection_date", group_by:="box_id"))
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Another option (if you want to create a separate layer) is to use a Virtual Layer:

```sql
select "key", "type", max("datefield") as latestdate, st_pointonsurface("geometry") as geom --Or just "geometry" if you want the original geometry, I want a point
from Refactored
group by "type"
```

[image]